# Not able to execute the SoapUI test cases from MAVEN

Tags: maven, soap, continuous-integration

I have my `XML` file which was generated using `Soap-UI` and our testers are able to execute the test case by calling the api's from `Soap-UI` with out any issues. But when the same I integrated as a part of continuous integration using `Maven` I am not getting the result as expected. All of the test cases are failing

Here is the `pom.xml` I have

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.smartbear.samples</groupId>
<artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Maven 2 SoapUI Sample</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
        <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
            <outputFolder>logs</outputFolder>
            <printReport>true</printReport>
            <junitReport>true</junitReport>
              <projectFile>/MyApp/soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
            </configuration> 
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.6</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>    
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>                             
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I am getting the following stack trace when I open up the test tab

> #### **Get - CustomerList Failed**
>
> ```
> SubmitException:
> com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Request$SubmitException:
> com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.RequestTransportRegistry$MissingTransportException:
> Missing protocol in endpoint [${endPoint}]
> ```
>
> ---

Comment: any luck can some one help me

Comment: Added `endpoint` in `POM.XML` getting the following error `Response status code:404 is not in acceptable list of status codes
</pre><hr/>`

Comment: Removed the dependencies and done some changes in XML that got generated by Soap UI, working as expected now